# Get UTM Zone from GeoTIFF (geotools java)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, geotools, utm

I've loaded a GeoTiff successfully in with geotools (21-SNAPSHOT), but I'm having trouble accessing the referenced UTM zone.

The code to read in the file is here:

```
File tiffFile = new File(filePath);
GeoTiffFormat format = new GeoTiffFormat();
Hints hint = new Hints();
hint.put(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
tiffReader = format.getReader(tiffFile, hint);
GridCoverage2D grid = tiffReader.read(null);
```

I'm inspecting the `GridCoverage2D` object in my debugger and have found the information in a few places.

The information I'm looking for here is the `"UTM zone 16N"`. Perhaps the zone is given in numerical form somewhere else in the object?

This is inside `GridCoverage2D->GridGeometry2D->CoordinateReferenceSystem2D`

[image: GridGeometry debugging]

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to access this information. 
There's no reference to the underlying transformation `conversionFromBase` in the top level object. None of the accessible methods get me anywhere closer.

Is there an encoded version somewhere in the `CoordinateReferenceSystem` metadata?

**EDIT**

The output of the `.toWKT()` method on my CoordinateReferenceSystem is below

`PROJCS["unnamed", 
  GEOGCS["GCS Name = unknown", 
    DATUM["Datum = unknown", 
      SPHEROID["Ellipsoid = unretrievable - using WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", -87.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH]]`

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a block like:

```
AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(file,hints);
GridCoverage2D coverage = reader.read(null);
crs = coverage.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
```

But if you are starting with a `GridGeometry` then it also has a `getCoordinateSystem` method you can use directly.

**EDIT**

Querying the internals of a `CoordinateReferenceSystem` is possible, what you get back tends to reflect what was provided by the input file.

I use `crs.getName()` which gives me "EPSG:WGS 84 / UTM zone 35S" but for a fuller investigation I used:

```
if (crs == null) {
  crs = cov.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();

  System.err.println("Set CRS to " + crs.getName());
  Collection<GenericName> alias = crs.getAlias();
  if (alias.isEmpty()) {
    System.err.println("No Alias");
  } else {
  for (Iterator iterator = alias.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    GenericName genericName = (GenericName) iterator.next();
    System.err.println(genericName);
  }
  }
  Set<ReferenceIdentifier> ids = crs.getIdentifiers();
  if (ids.isEmpty()) {
    System.err.println("No ids");
  } else {
    for (Iterator iterator = ids.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
      ReferenceIdentifier referenceIdentifier = (ReferenceIdentifier) iterator.next();

      System.err.println("id=" + referenceIdentifier);
    }
  }
  System.err.println(crs.toWKT());
}
```

for a full(ish) output of:

```
Set CRS to EPSG:WGS 84 / UTM zone 35S
No Alias
id=EPSG:32735
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 35S", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 27.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 10000000.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","32735"]]
```

It can sometimes be worth going back to the EPSG database so

```
crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:32735");
```

or whatever your `ReferenceIdentifier` was used directly may help.

Comment: I have a similar block where I read in the file initially, I just can't find the information I need inside the `CoordinateReferenceSystem` object

Comment: can you clarify your question then?

Comment: I've added my code for loading the TIFF and attempted to clarify the question.

Comment: It seems the metadata for my CRS is lacking in detail (see edit above). But the information exists lower down on the `conversionFromBase` transformation.